# xcode buttons overlap despite constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, constraints

I am working with a series of 4 buttons. All same width and height that combined stretch the width of the view.  I have tried visually constraining them to each other and to a label (also the width of the view) above them.  I used the Leading edge to view constraint on my far left button and trailing edge to view constraint on my far right button.  I also used horizontal space constraints (which should be zero) on all of my buttons. despite this when I run my simulator the third button over is always over lapping with the fourth to some degree.  I've gone through and deleted all the constraints and tried adding them again and the same over lap happened.  Is there something I am missing/doing wrong? Why wont my all buttons shrink to fit the view instead of overlapping?

Comment: Is it the case that you have four buttons that are all the same size, and that all have the same parent view, and you want to space them equally within that parent view?

Comment: Yes I want them to stay the same size and not leave the view. they all have horizontal constraints, equal widths constraints, and the two ends have leading and trailing constraints respectively

Comment: It might be worth running the app, pausing execution and typing `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` at the `(lldb)` prompt. Make sure you don't have any ambiguous constraints. Also, when you run this, are you getting any messages about unsatisfiable constraints in the console? Any constraint-related messages there at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something similar in my code, if u are setting button constraints programatically, i have a scrollview and a contentview inside it and setted constraints in storyboard, but other stuff i add programatically

```
button1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constX)

    constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    view.addConstraint(constTop)

    constL = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    view.addConstraint(constL)

    constR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
    view.addConstraint(constR)

    constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
    button1.addConstraint(constH)


    button2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constX)

    constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    view.addConstraint(constTop)

    constL = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    view.addConstraint(constL)

    constR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
    view.addConstraint(constR)

    constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
    button2.addConstraint(constH)


    button3.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constX)

    constL = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    view.addConstraint(constL)

    constR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
    view.addConstraint(constR)

    constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    view.addConstraint(constTop)

    constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
    button3.addConstraint(constH)

    button4.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constX)

    constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: button3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    view.addConstraint(constTop)

    var constBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
    view.addConstraint(constBottom)

    constL = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    view.addConstraint(constL)

    constR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: ContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
    view.addConstraint(constR)

    constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant:50)
    button4.addConstraint(constH)
```

So there are 4 buttons, constrained to themselves and button1.top to Contentview.Top and button4.Bottom to ContentView.Bottom